# Could not connect to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to connect to SharePoint Online using SharePoint Online Management Shell.
It works perfectly from my local machine so I know the url (https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com) is good and that my credentials are correct.

When I try the same command on my web server (Windows Server 2012 R2): Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com it always return the "Could not connect to SharePoint Online".
The web Server is using TLS 1.2 as requested, there is no access control enabled in SharePoint or Office 365 so I really don't know what is going on.
What could explain this error message?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try the followings:

1. Make sure that SharePoint Online Management Shell is up-to-date.
2. Run PowerShell in administrative mode.
3. Update the execution policy of the session by running the following command:

   Set-ExecutionPolicy Undefined
4. Connect to the SharePoint Admin URL that you're using by running the following command:

   Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com

For more information about this error, you can refer to the article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/errors-connecting-to-management-shell

### Update

Windows Server 2012 R2 is not supported for SharePoint Online Management Shell. From [the article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588):

[image]

Comment: @Kally-MFST, thank you for your help. I had already tried that and I keep getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: I researched again and found, Windows Server 2012 R2 is not supported for SharePoint Online Management Shell. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Kally-Msft for your effort. It is surprising as my SharePoint Online Management Shell works fine on an other web Server under Windows Server 2012 R2. I will continue to explore, perhaps a proxy or a firewall rule.